# Calling hubot help from other command

Tags: hubot

I am trying to call hubot help for unknown commands for  hubot. how can I call hubot help from another command like hubot test. Since I am using hubot help from external scripts file. I am not able to add robot.on inside it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to find the exact solution. But the following workaround for getting the help commands worked

```
helpCommands = robot.helpCommands() + '';
test = helpCommands.split(',');
for j in test
    msg.send "#{j}"
```